# How to make a tree command using Python3's argparse library?

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

I do not find a way to create this kind of arguments structure with the `argparse` package:

$ python3 prog.py [**A (a1 VAR | a2 | a3)** | B | C c]

I would like A to be a root for a sub-commands family, in my case a blacklist (./prog blacklist [add PATH | rm | ...]), but I also need two other features : `$ ./prog push FILE` and finally `$ ./prog --interactive`.

I've already taken a serious look at [the argparse documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html).
I've tried to use `add_mutually_exclusive_group()` to regroup a1, b1 and c1 but I'm stuck with this :

`ValueError: mutually exclusive arguments must be optional`

I did manage to have `python3 prog.py (A a1 a2| B | C c1)` using groups, but either I miss understood something, or `argparse` has nothing included for this case.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks for your time !

**EDIT :** I've finally managed to do what I was looking for. However, I am not convinced this is very clean. It could be great to have some packages which does it better than I.
Thanks to [this website](https://chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2014/03/21/python-multilevel-argparse.html#), I've found a way to achieve my goal. I attach the code if ever it interests anyone.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import argparse
from sys import argv


class CLI:
    """
    Class which represent the CLI's behaviour.
    Every function describes a subcommands tree and
    how the CLI should respond.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
            description='',
            usage='''cli <command> [<args>]'

Commands list:

cli blacklist     Interact with the blacklist.
cli interactive   Run an interactive mode for queries.
cli read <path>   Try to extract credentials.
'''
        )
        parser.add_argument('command', help='Subcommand to run')
        # only parsing the subcommand
        args = parser.parse_args(argv[1:2])
        if not hasattr(self, args.command):
            print('Unrecognized command')
            parser.print_help()
            exit(1)
        # use dispatch pattern to invoke method with same name
        getattr(self, args.command)()

    def blacklist(self):
        """
        Parser for blacklist methods.
        """
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
            description='',
            usage='''cli blacklist <subcommand> [<args>]

Subcommands list:

add <domain>          Add <domain> from the blacklist.
export <path>         Export blacklist as csv to <path>.
import <path> [-e]    Import <path> as csv. Erase existing blacklist if -e.
remove <domain>       Remove <domain> from the blacklist.
show                  Print the blacklist.
'''
        )
        parser.add_argument('subcommand')
        args = parser.parse_args(argv[2:3])
        if not hasattr(self, 'bl_%s' % (args.subcommand)):
            print('Unrecognized command')
            parser.print_usage()
            exit(1)
        getattr(self, 'bl_%s' % (args.subcommand))()

    def bl_add(self):
        print('add `%s` to the blacklist' % (argv[3:4][0]))

    def bl_export(self):
        print('export')

    def bl_import(self):
        print('import')

    def bl_remove(self):
        print('remove')

    def bl_show(self):
        print('show')

    def read(self):
        if len(argv) != 3:
            print('Wrong number of arguments')
            print('usage: cli read <path>')
            exit(1)
        print('process %s' % (argv[2:3][0]))

    def interactive(self):
        print('run interactive mode')

CLI()
```

Comment: `argparse` has only 2 ways of 'grouping' arguments - the simple mutually exclusive group, and subparsers.  There's no fancy nesting or and/any groupings.  'argument group' is just a help line tool, not a parsing one.  Putting a mutually-exclusive group inside another just just makes one larger one.

Comment: You usage lines are not particularly clear.  When I explored adding nested groups, formatting a meaningful usage line was one ot the tougher tasks.

Comment: About that `ValueError`, does that make sense?  `(A|B|C)` means you should be able to provide just one, and omit the others.  They all have to be optional - either as flagged arguments, or a `nargs='?'` positional (just one of those).